# AMP-AD issues with Google Ads

Tags: wordpress, responsive, amp-html, google-ads-script

We are having a bit of an issue with the `<amp-ad> </amp-ad>` tags on our website and we are wondering if anyone has had this issue and found a solution.

The site we're working on is https://www.digitalcitizen.life/

The pages where you can see our issue are: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/8-ways-start-control-panel-windows-10/ and https://www.digitalcitizen.life/razer-viper-8khz-review/

The issue is as follows:
We are serving AdSense ads, via the `<amp-ad></amp-ad>` and on mobile devices only the served ads ignore our settings and the ads are wider than the container, like in this screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/XSi5x2a0p

We have also tried using layout="responsive" to no avail.
Does anyone have any clue on how to solve this, and make the mobile ads respect the size we try to enforce? Thank you!

The code is as follows:

`

```
    <amp-ad class="digcit-ad" media="(min-width: 1744px)" type="adsense" layout="fixed" width="970" height="90"  data-ad-slot="SlotIDnumber" data-ad-client="ClientNumber"></amp-ad>

    <amp-ad class="digcit-ad" media="(min-width: 1168px) and (max-width: 1743px)" type="adsense" layout="fixed" width="728" height="90"  data-ad-slot="SlotIDnumber" data-ad-client="ca-ClientNumber"></amp-ad>

    <amp-ad class="digcit-ad" media="(min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1167px)" type="adsense" layout="fixed" width="580" height="400"  data-ad-slot="SlotIDnumber" data-ad-client="ClientNumber"></amp-ad>

    <amp-ad class="digcit-ad" media="(max-width: 991.98px)" type="adsense" layout="fixed" width="300" height="250"  data-ad-slot="SlotIDnumber" data-ad-client="ClientNumber"></amp-ad>
```

`